Multi-Party Computation tag synonyms
Based on what I’ve seen during my recent edit-frenzy, I would like to suggest the following tag-synonyms for the multiparty-computation tag:

secure-multiparty-computation
mpc (short for ”Multi-Party Computation”)
smpc (short for ”Secure Multi-Party Computation”)

That is, unless someone objects to this suggestion…

I think all your suggestions are good and the synonyms should be created. I'll add one more smc. I see that in papers sometimes. 

Just to be sure this doesn’t get lost in translation: poor me doesn’t have the 5 points needed to suggest those synonyms via the [tag:multiparty-computation] tag page… so, if the suggestions make sense – could you be so kind and use your über-admin powers to add them? That would be great. (Thanks!)

@e-sushi thanks for the reminder. Had meant to do that. I added the synonyms. Note that [tag:secure-multiparty-computation] was too long.

No prob… and thanks again.

"Secure Function Evaluation" too is cited some times in papers , not to be confused with functional encryption. 

But are secure function evaluation and multiparty computation the same thing?

yes, SFE is same as SMC. to best of my knowledge

@mikeazo Indeed, they are not the same thing! SFE is a so-called sub-problem of SMPC, but it’s not anywhere near what we might call “a synonym”. (In case of doubt, see Wikipedia's “Secure function evaluation” and Wikipedia's “Secure multi-party computation – Two-party_computation”.)
